# Do both receiving and sending end need to setup IBM MQ?

Tags: queue, jms, ibm-mq, message-queue

My application only reads messages from the IBM MQ. I am trying to understand, if one of the end is only reading messages from queue, do both sending and receiving ends need to setup JMS provider(IBM MQ)/Connection factories, Queue destination?What is the difference between JMS provide and Queue manager? Who needs to install JMS provider and Queue manager?

Comment: A application using IBM MQ Classes for JMS will need to have a IBM MQ Queue manager to connect to.  When you mention JMS Provider(IBM MQ) I believe you are referring to the Queue manager?

Comment: I am new to JMS and queues. I am trying to understand the differences between JMS provider, queue manager, destination queue. Is there any difference between queue and queue manager?

Comment: I just used the StackOverflow search box at the top of the page with the following terms "Difference between queue and queue manager" and came back with some results, the second in my list is "[Difference between Queue Manager and Queue in MQ
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754022/difference-between-queue-manager-and-queue-in-mq)".  Has some good info.  I'm sure a google search for the same will turn up many more references.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the queue manager as the server where queues and other MQ objects live. Your application is the client that connects to the server and interacts with the objects there.

IBM MQ server/queue manager IS your JMS provider. Your client application needs the IBM MQ implemented JMS libraries (IBM MQ Classes for JMS) and the JMS api which you can then use in your application to add parameters to your connection factory to connect to the queue manager. 
You can see a basic tutorial for a JMS MQ client application [here](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/).

Depending on who is in charge of your queue manager and how they have set things up, you should probably not be hard coding the queue manager and queue details in your client application. You should be getting the connection details from the JNDI store if you have an administrator who has set one up for you. See more at the bottom of the JMS tutorial I linked to, for how JMS works.